Can't remove header from specific page
I know this question was asked countless times here. But I can't find a way to completely remove my header from the Acknowledgements page, the ToC and Introduction (both will have 'Contents' in the header).
In my configuration.tex file I have defined the following header:
%% ADD SECTION AND CHAPTER TO HEADER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- use fancyplain instead fancy
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ #1}}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % Display section name in header
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % nbr of current page
%\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% default ist .4pt
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{.4pt}% default is 0pt

And in my main file, I simply include the different file composing my report:
\documentclass{report}
\input{Title & Configuration/configuration}


\begin{document}

\input{Title & Configuration/TitlePage} % title page covering

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Content/Aknowledgments}
% \newpage\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{Content/Introduction}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\chapter{Chapter}
\input{some_file}

No matter what I do, I can't seem to remove the header from specific pages.


And the introduction page even has "Contents":

Ultimately I would like the numbering to start at the Introduction page and not have any header in the table of content and acknowledgements.
Here is a test document to compile:
\documentclass{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Global configuration %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=10mm,
 heightrounded % ensures the height is adjusted so that an integer number of lines are accommodated in the text block
 }

%% ADD SECTION AND CHAPTER TO HEADER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- use fancyplain instead fancy
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ #1}}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % Display section name in header
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % nbr of current page
%\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% default ist .4pt
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{.4pt}% default is 0pt

\begin{document}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter*{Aknowledgments}

Some text to thank people

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter*{Introduction}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}

Some text

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2}

Some other text

\end{document}


Can you make a test document which we can compile without having access to your local files?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried to do that, I hope it works

Much better, thanks!

Thanks for your suggestion :)

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Thanks @Mensch ! It's not the first time I come here looking for a solution but that might be my very first question ^^


use \thispagestyle{empty} on the page where you want to remove the header

to change the page style of the toc, you could use \usepackage{tocloft} \tocloftpagestyle{empty}



\documentclass{report}

%% ADD SECTION AND CHAPTER TO HEADER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}% <- use fancyplain instead fancy
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ #1}}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % Display section name in header
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % nbr of current page
%\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}% default ist .4pt
\renewcommand{\plainheadrulewidth}{.4pt}% default is 0pt

\usepackage{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}


\newpage
\chapter*{Aknowledgments}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Some text to thank people

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\chapter*{Introduction}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}

Some text

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\section{Section 2}

Some other text

\end{document}



This does remove the header from the ToC page, however, the Acknowledgements page still have a header if I don't put the \thispagestyle{empty} directly in the file, took me a minute to realize that ! Thanks !

@ChrisZeThird I don't get a header on the Acknowledgements page.

Sorry I edited my comment, it does work now :)

Please note that \tocloftpagestyle{empty} changes only the pagestyle of the first page of the TOC (and LOF and LOT). If you want the following pages also to have empty pagestyle, when the TOC etc. is more than one page, you also have to give \pagestyle{empty} before the \tableofcontents etc.

Just in case you find it overkill to load a package for this, here are two alternative solutions for the Table of Contents:
1.
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\tableofcontents
\newpage




\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

The latter solution requires that your LaTeX installation isn't too old.

Thanks for the suggestion! I had recently found out about the \protect function to remove sections of Appendices in the ToC, so it makes a lot of sense. Also I am using Overleaf so I should be safe with the LaTeX environment :)

Overleaf or a LaTeX installation at your own computer doesn't make a difference.

@ChrisZeThird overleaf is notorious for only updating once a year and exiting projects will stay at the texlive version with  which you started them (unless you manually change the version), so using overleaf is a very likely cause for having an outdated latex distribution.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ho ! Okay well I didn't know that I just thought it would update frequently, good to know!
